# How to add more than one bitmap icon in markers for Google Maps?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, marker

```
IconGenerator iconFactory = new IconGenerator(this);
hM = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(lati1,longit1))
    .title("HostelM")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.parkingmarker)));

hM.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.parkingmarker));
```

I am trying to add a custom marker and a icon text simultaneously on a single marker. But it only shows me either my custom marker or my text. Any solution or alternative for same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by inflating your custom layout,

Step 1: Create Your custom layout.
lay_marker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_marker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/map_car_running" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_marker_lebel"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minWidth="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Step 2: Get Bitmap of Custom Marker

```
 public Bitmap getMarkerIconWithLabel(Context mContext,String label) {
        IconGenerator iconGenerator = new IconGenerator(mContext);
        View markerView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.lay_marker, null);
        ImageView imgMarker = markerView.findViewById(R.id.img_marker);
        TextView tvLabel = markerView.findViewById(R.id.tv_label);

        imgMarker.setImageResource(R.drawable.car);


        tvLabel.setText(label);
        iconGenerator.setContentView(markerView);
        iconGenerator.setBackground(null);

        return iconGenerator.makeIcon(label);
    }
```

Step 3: Apply this bitmap to Marker

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(lati1,longit1))
    .title("HostelM")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(this,"Label")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code

```
LatLng source, LatLng dest;

LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
IconGenerator iconFactory = new IconGenerator(this);
iconFactory.setRotation(0);
iconFactory.setContentRotation(0);


MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
markerOptions.position(source);
iconFactory.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_BLUE);
markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon("Label 1")));
map.addMarker(markerOptions);
builder.include(source);

markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
markerOptions.position(dest);
iconFactory.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_GREEN);
markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon("Label 2")));
map.addMarker(markerOptions);
builder.include(dest);

LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

int width = mSupportMapFragment.getView().getMeasuredWidth();
int height = mSupportMapFragment.getView().getMeasuredHeight();
int padding = (int) (width * 0.15);

CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width, height, padding);

map.animateCamera(update);
```